# how to set the name attribute for dymamically created div?..in jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I created a `div` dynamically whenever I clicking the "Add More" button.  This is how I created my `div`, showing below:

```
     <div id="row-template">
        <div class="cell" >
          <input type="text" value="" class="part-number"/>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Now I want to set the name attribute for this `div`:

`<div class="cell" ><input type="text" value="" class="part-number"/></div>`

I will create multiple `div`s and I want to get entire values in my java using `request.getParameter("The Part Number Text Box Name");`

My issue is my java variable is being `null` (`String Part Number = request.get Parameter("The Part Number Text Box Name")`)

It is  giving me null values because I am unable set the name attribute for this text box and I have to set the unique name with index then only its easy to get in java with indexes.

The issues I want to resolve are:

1. I want to get my entire text box values to my java through  `request.getParameter(...)` with the help of index
2. I want get my all row's length how many `div` I created.

Please help me out from these issues...Thanks in advance

Comment: see i want to get multiple created div values so i choosed the name parameter to get all the values to java with the unique name help of index values..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the name attribute to the input element instead of the div element?

To borrow a bit from the previous answer:

```
var cnt = 0;
    $("#mybutton").on("click", function () {
         var html = "";
         html += "<div id='row-template'>";
         html += "<div class='cell'>";
        html += "<input name='myName" + cnt +"' type='text' value='' class='part-number'/>";
      html += "</div>";
         html += "</div>";
        console.log(html);
         $("#WhereToAppend").append(html);
         cnt++;
    });
```

The code above is jquery code that will add a new input (and surrounding div) element to the DOM.  It will give each input element a unique name by appending the value of "cnt" to the string "myName", in effect giving the input element a name of "myName0", "myName1", "myName2" for each time you trigger this specific click event.

From the W3Schools definition of the Input element:

*The name attribute specifies the name of an  element.
The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.
Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.*

Comment: so can u give any solution for me to get multiple created div that text box values to java using req.getParam...

Comment: If every input element has a name attribute, they will show up in the post parameters.  Whether you are using java or .net is immaterial.  You need each INPUT element to have name attribute - not the DIV elements.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you append the div dynamically but in jquery it will look like this :

```
var count = 0;
$("MyAddButton").click(function () {
     var html = "";
     html += '<div id="row-template">';
    //put the name you want here
     html += '<div class="cell" name="myName" ><input type="text" value="" class="part-number"/</div>'
     html += '</div>';
     $("WhereToAppend").append(html)
     count++;
});
```

Comment: right @Mathieu Labrie Parent i set the attribute name for that div id but i could not get that on jave its giving null value when usingreq.getParameter so how can i overcome this?...

Comment: I'm gessing that the getParameter is looking in the querystring. The div don't get pass in the querystring when you submit a form, only input. You could put that value into a hiddenfield.

Comment: no @Mathieu Labrie Parent if directly putting like( <input type="text" value="" id ="arrayLength" name="part-number"/>) this value is getting in req.getParam but if setting name attributes with the current index values for that time it is not taking this value getting "null"..

Answer (score -1):

I may not have a full answer for you but hopefully this will lead you in the right direction.

1)
If your page is invoked like this:

`http://<your_server>:<your_port>/mytest.jsp?crazyParamName=crazyParamAnswer`

You can use:

`String answer = request.getParameter( 'crazyParamName' );`

and the variable `answer` will be a `String` with the value: `crazyParamAnswer`

Use it to create your new inputs by inserting it into the page with a scriptlet like this `<%= anwser %>`

2) You can count how many divs you create when you click on the 'add more' button (using jQuery, I am assuming)

`var numberOfCells = $('#row-template').find('.cell').size();`

So, when you create a new button, you simply add one to the existing `numberOfCells` and use it as your index. Every time the button is clicked, the index will go up by one.